# Razor page gives the error the name 'Model' does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

On a regular Razor page I have the red underlines with the error message on 
Model, ViewBag, etc.
The intellisense does not work but the code compiles and runs fine.

There are lots of similar questions in StackOverflow but in my case this happens with a File/New project (MVC) as well as on any project that I have so it can't be a missing or incorrect line in a Web.Config etc.

I'm using VS 2015 Enterprise on Windows 10.

I had recently upgraded the PC to Windows 10 and VS2015

Any suggestions what may be causing this?

I had tried the following with no luck :

-simply waiting

-cleaning / rebuilding the project

-removing bin folder

-restarting VS

-repair install VS

Comment: This happens to me sometimes, and just by waiting it seems to work it out. Just open the view and click in it, and wait and see what happens

Comment: The web.config in the views folder is likely incorrect, wrong version of razor or MVC dlls is often one cause, but really it can be numerous things. Basically you have something misconfigured or MVC isn't installed

Comment: also check your running VS in admin mode.

Comment: @Liam As I wrote in the question, I get this with a file new project as well. So misconfigured web.config cannot be the issue.

Comment: Have you tried unloading the project and loading again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who may have a similar issue:
Uninstalling and Reinstalling VS2015 solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

As the code runs fine it seems as if the intellisense is being a bit poor.
You say you have recently upgraded to VS2015. In my experience the intellisense in VS takes time to "bed in". Certainly in VS2013 it would perform terribly slow and wasn't better until one of the service packs came out (I think it was #2).

If this is really a case of you creating a new project and it complaining before you've made any code changes then there is nothing you can do other than run VS2015 as an Administrator a few times and wait for it to sort itself out. Get any Windows Updates / Service Packs as well.